# How to plot text along curve plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, matlab-figure

I'm trying to plot text along one of my curved plot lines on MATLAB.
I can only find information on how to plot text at a certain angle, although I want it to go along the plot line.

Comment: The function you are looking for is called `text()`

Comment: Yes, but I need the text to be at the same angle as the line I've plotted.

Comment: You've used the words "line" and "curve" interchangeably but one is much harder than the other, do you want text to run in a straight line but at an angle, or to follow some arbitrary curve where each letter sits "normal" to the curve?